# Equals conditions in outer joins with NHibernate ICriteria/QueryOver query

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, icriteria

How do I do a *equals* condition in an outer join in Nhibernate/QueryOver/ICriteria?

The only way I have found to compare `surveyRequest.Survey.Id` with `surveyID` below is with `IsIn`.

```
SystemUser systemUser= null;
SurveyRequests surveyRequest = null;

var query = Session.QueryOver<SystemUser>(() => systemUser)
    .Left.JoinAlias(
        () => systemUser.SurveyRequests, 
        () => surveyRequest,
        Restrictions.On(()=>surveyRequest.Survey.Id).IsIn(new object []{surveyID }))
//                                                   ^^^^
```

*(I am reusing an earlier [query question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113972/521554).)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `.Where()` part of `Restrictions`

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<SystemUser>(() => systemUser)
    .Left.JoinAlias(
        () => systemUser.SurveyRequests, 
        () => surveyRequest,
        //Restrictions.On(()=>surveyRequest.Survey.Id).IsIn(new object []{surveyID }))
        Restrictions.Where(()=>surveyRequest.Survey.Id == surveyID ))
```